# python 2.6 TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.6

I dont understand the reason of this TypeError

script:

```
import os
import shutil

src1 = os.listdir("/usr/dir1")
dst1 = os.listdir("/usr/dir2")


for file in src1:
    if file not in dst1:
        shutil.copy(file, dst1)
```

Error:

```
File "/scripts/trans_dir_balancing.py", line 14, in <module>
    shutil.copy(file, dst1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 82, in copy
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

because ***dst1*** in your code is not path, it's a list of paths. It should be path (string), please take a look on the [shutil.copy()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) and also on the [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to copy files from one folder to another, you just need to specify the destination directory as the second argument in shuti.copy.

```
import os
import shutil

src = '/usr/dir1'
dst = '/usr/dir2'

for file in os.listdir(src):
    if file not in os.listdir(dst) and os.path.isfile(file):
        # copy file to dst dir if not exists
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, file), dst)
```

Comment: This will raise `IOError: [Errno 21]` if a dir is found in the source directory, that's why a `if os.path.isfile(file):` is necessary. Also it might worth mentioning that the OP is overriding the builtin `file` object and the variable should be renamed.

Comment: Good points. For point 1, unless there is a chance it can happen, I dont think the program needs to be overcomplicated. Though I will edit the code to mention that in case the OP is not aware. Thanks.

Comment: This code has an unsafe race condition. By relying on `if file not in os.listdir(dst)` you are assuming the target file name cannot be created in the target directory before the following call to `shutil.copy`, which is not generally true. Since `shutil.copy` overwrites existing files, this is unsafe. You should consider using a different API that doesn't overwrite, and skip the existence check in favor of a `try/except` block to handle the overwrite condition.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is old and dated. However, I found it funny that months later I am working on a similar project. I was working on a program to back up my home directory.
This is how I did it.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'input path of files to be backed up'):
for ckfile in files:
    for root2, dirs2, files2 in os.walk(r'input your destination directory'):
        if ckfile not in files2:
            print"Backing up the file "+ckfile
            copyf = os.path.join(root,ckfile)
            shutil.copy2(copyf, r'input your destination directory')    
        else:
            print "The file "+ckfile+" is already backed up"
```

Now, what I need is a way to check for native compression. I considered using zip, but that would require that I change the code that I have so far. I'm probably just going to have the program test to see if what operating system is being used, and then just use that operating systems commands to compress the file.